# You can spend all your love making time?

Tags: phrases, lyrics

"You can spend all your time making money; You can spend all your love making time." from the song *Take it to the limit* by The Eagles, the phrase "love making time" makes me wonder.

Does it mean someone refuses to make love (supposed that takes a long time on dating) in order to spend more time to make more money? I mean, "love-making" is a phrase to decorate the word "time", just like "you can spend all your precious time".

or

Spend love to make time, just like "Spend time to make money"? This becomes obvious when I read the answers to this [question](http://www.experienceproject.com/question-answer/You-Can-Spend-All-Your-Time-Making-Money-You-Can-Spend-All-Your-Love-Making-Time-Which-Do-You-Prefer-Dont-Say-Both/352605). So my question: How can one spend love to make time? Love is what you gain after spending a lot of time with other (if lucky), how can you spend love if you don't gain it first by spending time?

Comment: The answer may be primarily opinion based, considering it's one's interpretation of lyrics instead of sourced documentation. "Making time [for other pursuits in life]" may prevent you from spending time being with the ones you love or love you. There are 24 hours a day, about a third of which you sleep, are you spending [time for] love, or are you making time [for other pursuits]. Again, opinion. No real sources.

Comment: SrJoven, I believe the idiom referenced is not "making time *for*", but the (hipper, at the time) "making time *with*", meaning frivolous, lighthearted romance, or general teenage groping. The parallel is "you can waste all your *time* in pursuing *money*" vs "you can waste all your *love* pursuing *sex*".

Comment: @DanBron Alas, 'tis true. Makes more sense. The lyric explanation site I visited went all crazy about other non-sexual pursuits.

Comment: I imagine that's cause the idiom "Making time *with* Sally" has essentially been lost, so now the lyric is archorless and confusing (and unlike prose, people are just *rabid* about assigning meanings to lyrics; a lyric *simply cannot* be meaningless).

Comment: @DanBron yes! "You can spend all your love making time _with_ Sally", that makes perfect sense in the context of this song.

Comment: of course, obviously, it's a play on "making time" as Dan outlines.  I guess if Kenster is a non-native speaker he did not know this.  @SrJoven, I guess that's the heart of the question here

Comment: OT: "interpretation of lyrics"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the great lyrics in modern English of course,

it's straightforward,

> You can spend ... all your time ... making money,
>
> You can spend ... all your love ... making time,
>
> If it all fell to pieces tomorrow - would you still be mine?

Note that "making time" is a slang phrase for (in short) "trying to get sex"; it's not unlike the phrase "to score" which you may know?

The first phrase exhorts you, on the practical side of life, to not spend your whole life, worrying about making money.

The second phrase exhorts you, on the love and romance side of life, to not spend all your time just trying to "get sex" -- to "score" -- keep a space for actual love.

If you go ahead and read all the lyrics ... [put me on a highway...](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/eagles/takeittothelimit.html)

..it's generally a song about the loss of things you missed out on (a woman who loved me - and I didn't even know); the two lines you quote are the very epitome of this, the protagonist is even offering it to us as advice .. but for himself ...

In the end though - heartbreakingly - the main character's only response is to just keep moving; too hop in a car and cruise away in to the desert.

The song seems to have been primarily written by, associated with, Randy Meisner. (Obviously, it is one of The Eagles many Very Famous songs from the period.)

In any event in answer to your question, you may not have been familiar with **"making time"** as a phrase associated with "getting sex". It's not unlike "making out" which you may have heard. So the pair of lines are a turn-about on (A) not wasting your life chasing money, and (B) not wasting your love merely chasing sex.

Comment: In my opinion line two can be taken as a pun with two alternate meanings, one as you detailed above, the other as *you can spend all your lovemaking time.*  In this second reading, it combines with the first line to yield an overall meaning of "don't waste the time you could be spending making love (having sex) on making money."

Comment: -1 See Chris Sunami's comment. Lyrics are lyrics.

Comment: Guessing you have seen, not heard, the lyrics.  It's two totally separate words, and it's very obviously a philosophical comment on "making time".